# How to include phonegap application in the iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am creating a phonegap application in ios and i am following below mentioned link

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html

It is said in the link that we need to download the phone gap, which i had done already
 and then click on the cordova based application, but in my app I am not getting the options 
 to select the same.

So can anyone suggest how it can be done?

Comment: you are saying you did not find phone gap template in Xcode/

Comment: @Charan Yes. I am not getting phone gap template.I had downloaded Phonegap 2.9.1

Comment: i got same issue and it was fixed... please see my answer if you need any information more than that i'll help on it

Comment: @Charan Hi Install node.js and also have Phonegap 2.9.1.So what next? How to install phone gap and cordova?

Comment: You don't need node.js is you are trying to work with version 2.9.1 of PhoneGap.  The opposite is true too; For later versions of PhoneGap, you just need Node.js.  Try reading the [latest version of the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide) for the "modern" way to use phonegap.

Comment: Is the issue fixed? its a simple way around to get it worked on mac

Comment: @Charan.Yes i had successfully created cordova project but would like to know whether I can import my existing html files in the project

Comment: @Charan.I achieved to do it using your link

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap installation process has been changed. You will not get any template in Xcode and we can do is creating app in terminal

```
List of this you need to install phoneGap are

1. node.js
2. cordova
3. phonegap

first install node.js and then phone gap/cordova 

once your installation is completed open terminal and then create a cordova based application

use this for creating process   
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html  

this for plugins    
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs
```

Answer (score 0):

cd to your workspace

```
cd /Users/xxxx/Desktop
```

create cordova project

```
cordova create your-project-name
```

cd to your project

```
cd your-project-name
```

add ios platform

```
cordova platform add ios
```

build your project using cordova build

```
cordova build ios
```

done !!

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/21/crud-operation-using-jquery-mobile-on-android-part-1/